# How to generate an alphanumeric ID in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, sequence, auto-increment

I have a table named GROUPS which has a column **GROUP_ID** whose values are

> GRP001, GRP002, GRP003

and so on. Now every time I insert a new row I have to insert it with a
 (current) GROUP_ID= (highest)GROUP_ID+ 1 , for example if highest GROUP_ID= GRP003 I have to generate a new GROUP_ID GRP004 when I insert a new row.

How can I do this using java?

I am currently using Hibernate along with Struts 2 in my program

Is there any way to deal with this using hibernate? Or will I have to write additional code to lock the table, check the db for max Id (and then increment it) and finally release the lock?

Comment: What database is this running on?  Look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346450/how-to-get-the-auto-increment-primary-key-value-in-mysql-using-hibernate  You can probably write a class to generate keys. not sure.  Why must the group id have "GRP" preceding it instead of just a straight sequence #?

Comment: This application is supposed to be database independent that why I am using Hibernate and it is predefined that group id should have "GRP" preceding it.

Answer (score 1):

I remember solving a problem similar to this once. What I did was I create a custom primary key generator as supported by hibernate.

This guy explains it clearly here: ["Custom Hibernate Primary Key Generator"](http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/)

Basically you just need to implement `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator` and all should be set.

Just be aware that the solution implemented in the example above is database dependent. But I think sometimes common sense should prevail over overengineering.

Comment: I read the link you suggested, but I did not get this point "First I created a database sequence to use. Then I implemented org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator" , where do I need to create this sequence? Is it on GROUPS table and how?

Comment: Most databases have a sequence generation function either as a native object, or a function call.  You may have to write a custom tenerator per database type to generate a sequence.

Comment: @user2077648 `sequence` is mostly an Oracle thing, so make sure you are using Oracle. For more explanation about sequence refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798766/how-to-create-an-oracle-sequence-starting-with-max-value-from-a-table

Comment: I am not allowed to implement a sequence for my table