# How to generate Custom Id in JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i want generate Custom Id in JPA it must be primary key of table.
there are many examples to create Custom Id using hibernate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158509/how-to-generate-custom-id-using-hibernate-while-it-must-be-primary-key-of-table) 
i want same implementation but in JPA.The id must be alphanumeric like `STAND0001`

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as spring JPA. There is JPA, the specification, and some implementations of JPA, like Hibernate or EclipseLink. Spring doesn't have, and is not a JPA implementation. So check the documentation of your **actual** JPA implementation.

Comment: JB Nizet thanks for your reply ..i will edit question.. can you please tell me how to generate custom id in JPA

Comment: the id must be combination of string and numbers

Comment: i am using dependency spring-boot-starter-data-jpa version 1.4.7.RELEASE and implementation in hibernate

Comment: Which itself depends on hibernate. So you're using hibernate. So check the documentation of hibernate.

Comment: Can you post some code, i.e your entity/bo/model and how you want to generate your primary key? i.e number or string?

Comment: Sreenath Reddy ..edit same in question

Comment: I think the question was how to create generator not depending on specific JPA implementation. Looks like JPA doesn't have such functionality which is a pity, because I see no problem to define it in JPA.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it using `GenericGenerator` like this :

```
 @Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "client_id", strategy = "com.eframe.model.generator.ClientIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "client_id")  
    @Column(name="client_id")
    private String clientId;
}
```

and the custom generator class (will add prefix to the ID, you can make it do what you like):

```
public class ClientIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {

    String prefix = "cli";
    Connection connection = session.connection();

    try {
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select count(client_id) as Id from Client");

        if(rs.next())
        {
            int id=rs.getInt(1)+101;
            String generatedId = prefix + new Integer(id).toString();
            return generatedId;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: GenericGenerator is from hibernate package, and the question was how to do that independently of JPA provicder

Comment: @Marx I think you'll have to use the SessionCustomizer in EclipseLink. There is no mention of the said behavior in the JSR 338.

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.7 with Hibernate 5.6.9 you have to use `SharedSessionContractImplementor` instead of `SessionImplementor`

Answer (score 1):

Written on: 15-09-2023
This code above will not work anymore so here is the new code:

```
@Override
public Object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object){

    String prefix = "cli";
JdbcConnectionAccess con = session.getJdbcConnectionAccess();
        
            try {
                JdbcConnectionAccess jdbcConnectionAccess = session.getJdbcConnectionAccess();
                Connection connection = jdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection();
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                String query = "select count(client_id) as Id from Client";

                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

                if (resultSet.next()) {
                     int id=resultSet.getInt(1)+101;
                     String generatedId = prefix + new Integer(id).toString();
                     return generatedId;
                }

                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
return null;
}}
```