# Is there a way to create String sequence using @GeneratedValue with prefix?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to create a sequence with prefix "CID_00001" (example):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)   
private String id;
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: why does it need that prefix?

Comment: you can use genericGenerator, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259048/how-to-generate-custom-id-in-jpa

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that using a [custom id generator](https://thoughts-on-java.org/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/).

The easiest way is to extend Hibernate's `SequenceStyleGenerator`, which implements the access to the database sequence (incl. a few interesting optimizations)

```
public class StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;

    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat, super.generate(session, object));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
    numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

After you've implemented your own id generator, you can reference it in a `@GenericGenerator` annotation.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "book_seq")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "book_seq", 
        strategy = "org.thoughts.on.java.generators.StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator", 
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50"),
            @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER, value = "CID_"),
            @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER, value = "%05d") })
    private String id;

    ...
}
```

Comment: @ThorbenJanssen sir, doing this way we get hibernate_sequence table.how to get separate tables entity wise. Like ```@SequenceGenerator(name = "batch_seq", sequenceName = "batch_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize=1)```

Comment: Hi Thorben in this -- @Parameter(name = StringPrefixedSequenceIdGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "50")
.
what does value 50 represent and what does changing the number changes in id generation ?

Comment: I had pretty same implementation as your example. Now I'm wondering if we can use it type-safe in Hibernate 6?

Comment: I found the answer myself, since Hibernate 6.2 and later, @GenericGenerator provide `type` to help strategy declared prettier: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the database sequence for generating the PK. So add a trigger before inserting into the table. e.g., (in oracle )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sometable_trigger  
BEFORE INSERT ON SomeTable
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT 'CID_' || to_char(sometable_seq.NEXTVAL, "00009")
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

assumption:  sequence name as "**sometable_seq**" and id column name id