# How create a custom prefixed id jpa hibernate with @TableGenerator and reset the counter every year per location

Tags: hibernate, jpa, id-generation

I have a different product made from differents places. I need to create a custom key.

Product
String id
String name
String description
String source
...

Id is a String with this format and the counter must be reseted every year  year-codsource-0000001   eg.

next year
PT00A-00001
US00A-00001

I tried using @Tablegenerator and created a table CONTROL_IDS

| PREFIX | COUNTER |
| --- | --- |
| PT00A | 1 |
| US00A | 4 |

`@TableGenerator(name = "idgen",table = "CONTROL_IDS",pkColumnName = "PREFIX",valueColumnName = "COUNTER",pkColumnValue = "PT00A", allocationSize=1)`

Or even can select the prefix dinamically

`@TableGenerator(name = "idgen", table = "CONTROL_IDS", pkColumnName = "PREFIX",            valueColumnName = "COUNTER", pkColumnValue = "{prefixname}", allocationSize=1)`

Thank you for any guide

I tried using @TableGenerator and @GenericGenerator
and making a class to create prefixed value to the counter
or exits other kind of generators?

Thank you for any guide.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587520/is-there-a-way-to-create-string-sequence-using-generatedvalue-with-prefix/55588963#55588963

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create String sequence using @GeneratedValue with prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55587520/is-there-a-way-to-create-string-sequence-using-generatedvalue-with-prefix)