# Does the JPA standard provide a mechanism to allow developers to write an ID generator?

Tags: java, jpa

Hibernate supports a custom ID generator as noted in [How to generate Custom Id in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259048/how-to-generate-custom-id-in-jpa)

I was wondering, is there a JPA standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can write your own logic to assign primary key in a `PrePersist` lifecycle callback method.

This can further be expanded to use an `EntityListener` as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006736/242042 which allows you to inject Spring managed beans that your `PrePersist` operation would require if the `EntityListener` is managed by Spring.

If the `EntityListener` is not managed by Spring, ThreadLocal may be an alternative (rel: [Is it safe to pass in the Spring Application Context into a ThreadLocal associated with a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321914/is-it-safe-to-pass-in-the-spring-application-context-into-a-threadlocal-associat?noredirect=1#comment111971158_63321914))

Comment: I guess you check if it is "new" if the ID is `null` assuming it is a nullable value