# How to put prefix when create a custom id generator in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a custom ID for my Java Spring Boot project with format something like this `BDI-100`. I know how to setup the number part but have no idea how to put a prefix on it. I have tried a solution from this [thread in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259048/how-to-generate-custom-id-in-jpa) but it seems like it can not match with my project because of some different versions with mine.

Here is the spec of my project:

- built with Spring Tool Suite 4.18.0.RELEASE
- Java 17
- Spring Boot v3.1.3
- Built on top of ubuntu 22.04

and this is my model class. Perhaps can give the clue. Thank you for any hand guys!

```
package com.recruittest.bosnet.model;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "bosnet_people")
public class People {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "people_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PeopleIdGenerator", initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PeopleIdGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date birthday;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People [id=" + id + ", fullName=" + fullName + ", birthday=" + birthday + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `CustomIdGenerator` class that extends the `IdentifierGenerator`,  this way:

```java
public class CustomIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        String prefix = "BDI";
        String query = "SELECT MAX(people_id) FROM bosnet_people";
        Connection connection = session.getJdbcConnectionAccess().obtainConnection();

        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String lastId = rs.getString(1);
                if (lastId != null) {
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(lastId.substring(prefix.length())) + 1;
                    return prefix + "-" + number;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Unable to generate ID", e);
        }

        return prefix + "-" + 100; // Initial value if no records are present
    }
}
```

This generator will be responsible for generating the custom IDs.

Next, apply your custom ID generator to your `People` class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "bosnet_people")
public class People {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-id", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @GenericGenerator(name = "custom-id", strategy = "your.package.here.CustomIdGenerator")
   @Column(name = "people_id")
   private String id;

   // ... other fields and methods
}
```

Check this out:

- [IdentifierGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/id/IdentifierGenerator.html)
- [GenericGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, it run without error. But for some reason, it doesn't auto generate `people_id` when I insert data into column `full_name` and `birthday`. The ID also must be manually inserted and it can accept any format in it.

I also only can use this `Connection conn = (Connection) session.getJdbcConnectionAccess();` instead of this `Connection connection = session.connection();` because I can't find `.connection()` from my version. What kind of `Connection` that you use here? Is it this one `import java.sql.Connection;`?

Comment: 1) About the **Auto-Generation Issue** try to change the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. 2) "*The ID also must be manually inserted and it can accept any format in it*", you should put it in the question, 'couse maybe you are into a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). 3) Yes, it is `java.sql.Connection`, and `session.getJdbcConnectionAccess()` is incorrect does not provide the same functionality as `session.connection()`.

Comment: `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` doesn't work either. With that 2nd point you highlight I mean 'can only be,,' not 'must be..'. Checking at my Hibernate version, it is version 6.2.7 Final and turn out at this version `.connection()` is already deprecated since Hibernate 4. They replace it with this `session.doWork(new Work() {...})`. Will try to figure this out. Thanks by the hand anyway

Comment: My fault about the `.connection()` I've forget to check the version. I updated my answer.

Comment: About the 2 point, what I mean with [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) is: You tried to create a `Generator` but if the id can be manually inserted, maybe a `Generator` ins't the best solution for you.