# JPA Hibernate custom sequence generator for id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two Entities named Agency and Pay. The Relationship between them is one-to-many(one Agency has many Pay).
the agency table has a foreign key in Pay
and Pay has a composite key: pay.id and agency.id
I want to have a custom sequence generator for Pay.id where it's possible to have :

### Agency.id ||  pay.id

---

### 1                ||    P00001

### 1      ||    P00002

### 1      ||    P00003

### 2      ||    P00001

### 2      ||    P00002

### 3       ||   P00001

### 4      ||    P00002

Thanks for your help

edit : i want to start the sequence for every new agency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Custom Id using hibernate while it must be primary key of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158509/how-to-generate-custom-id-using-hibernate-while-it-must-be-primary-key-of-table)

Comment: in the link you give me,  the id generated is not repeated ,

Comment: How do you generate a `pay.id` value now?

Comment: @cepr0  strategy = GenerationType.AUTO   but i want to generate it like the example i wrote on the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing a generator I can recommend you another approach with using [@OrderColumn](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-unidirectional-ordered-list-order-column-example) and [@Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula) annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Agency {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mapedBy = "agency", cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
   @OrderColumn(name = "order_num")
   @ListIndexBase(1)
   private final List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();

   public Agency addPayment(Payment payment) {
      payment.setAgency(this);
      this.payments.add(payment);
      return this;
   }

   // ...
} 

@Entity    
public class Payment {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(optional = false)
   private Agency agency;

   @Formula(value = "CONCAT(agency_id, 'P', LPAD(order_num, 5, 0))")
   private String number;

   // ...
}
```

In this case the `payment` table will have additional column `order_num` with Agency relative order number of each its payment (1, 2, 3...).

With `@Formula` you can render this number on the `number` column. Be aware that the @Formula annotation takes a native SQL clause which can affect database portability (it's MySQL dialect in the example).

**UPDATED**

To make `@OrderColumn` work it's necessary to save `Payment` 'through' `Agency` and use helper method `addPayment(Payment payment)` since this 'one-to-many' association is bidirectional (more info is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional)):

```
final Payment payment1 = new Payment();
final Payment payment2 = new Payment();
final Agency agency = new Agency();
agency.addPayment(payment1);
agency.addPayment(payment2);

agencyRepo.save(agency);
```

Comment: it's possible to program the formula ?  in every start of the year reset the number of payment to begin with P0001/YY (yy: year) again ?

Comment: @yougerrard No. But you can add year to `@Formula`: `@Formula(value = "CONCAT(agency_id, 'P', LPAD(order_num, 5, 0), '/',  DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), "%y")")`