# String ID Primary Key generator in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, id-generation

I know that we can generate a random UUID -

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String myId;
```

But UUID is a String if size 32. How can i generate a random alphanumeric string of size 6 and store as ID?

I want to store this in MongoDB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Custom Id using hibernate while it must be primary key of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158509/how-to-generate-custom-id-using-hibernate-while-it-must-be-primary-key-of-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create a custom ID generator by implementing hibernate's `IdentifierGenerator`.

```
public class SomeCustomGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate() {...}
}
```

And then use it:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "cust-generator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "cust-generator", strategy = "com...generator.SomeCustomGenerator")
private String myId;
```

Take a look at the [example](http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/)

Comment: can i asking you, is there alternative to get sequence in hibernate beside using query ?