# Spring Boot and Hibernate Dynamic Id Generator for invoice Number

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on Spring boot Application with hibernate to create simple invoice.
I want to generate invoice number through hibernate in the following format 
as below

`YEAR/MONTH/Number(Will Increase)`

**The above sequence is dependent on invoice date.**

Month and year values do change based on the current Date.
Once the year completed, let say after the completion of one financial
year the sequence again start from the beginning, like month/Year/number.

I have tried to Sequence Generator , table Generator . My Code snippet is as below :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "year_gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "year_gen", strategy = "com.example.generator.CustomGenerator")
@Column(name = "invoice_no")
private String invoiceno;
```

But  I am  not getting any idea that how to make it dependable on Invoice Date.
My  Generator is below :

```
public class CustomGenerator  implements IdentifierGenerator { 

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor sessionImpl, Object data)
    throws HibernateException {
        Serializable result = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            String prefix = "";

            DateTimeFormatter newPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM"); 

            LocalDate ldObj = LocalDate.now();
            String yyyymm = newPattern.format(ldObj).toString();
            prefix = "INV/"+yyyymm+"/";
            connection = sessionImpl.connection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();                   
             try {  
                 resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select max(id)+1 from invoice");
             } catch(Exception ex) {

             }

            if(resultSet.next()) {
                int nextValue = resultSet.getInt(1);                
                String suffix = String.format("%05d", nextValue + 1);               
                result = prefix.concat(suffix);
                System.out.println("Custom generated Sequence value : "+result);
            } else
            {
                 int nextValue = 1;                
                 String suffix = String.format("%05d", nextValue + 1);               
                 result = prefix.concat(suffix);    
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you share what you have written in your CustomGenerator

Comment: I have Updated my Question With Generator Code. Please Let me know how pass date value from Controller to Generator

Comment: Try to see best answer in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31180058/8992586

Comment: Is it possible to pass date value to generator class through controller.